# How can i translate an Oracle MERGE statement to a T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, merge

In one of the books that I am reading it shows how to merge records from 2 different tables and here is the code below and this is in Oracle SQL I believe.

```
merge into emp_commission ec
using (select * from emp) emp
   on (ec.empno=emp.empno)
when matched then
   update set ec.comm = 1000
   delete where (sal < 2000)
when not matched then
   insert (ec.empno, ec.enme, ec.deptno, ec.comm)
   values (emp.empno, emp.ename, emp.deptno, emp.comm)
```

I have tried to run this in SQL Server but I got ***A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)*** error.I have added the semi-colon but still getting the same error.

Comment: PL/SQL is a procedural (imperative) programming language that works closely together with Oracle SQL. The MERGE statement is Oracle SQL (and Oracle implemented the SQL Standard definition and syntax of MERGE). What you have here has **nothing** to do with PL/SQL. Understand that PL/SQL is **not** the name of the Oracle version of SQL. I will edit your post to correct this.

Comment: Then: What book is that? One thing stands out immediately: Why `using (select * from emp) emp`?  Why not just `using emp`? If that is the overall quality of the book, you might as well look for a different one.

Comment: @mathguy The book is SQL Cookbook. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge into emp_commission ec
using (select * from emp) emp
   on (ec.empno=emp.empno)
when matched and 
sal < 2000 THEN
delete
when matched then
   update 
   set ec.comm = 1000
when not matched then
   insert (empno, enme, deptno, comm)
   values (emp.empno, emp.ename, emp.deptno, emp.comm);
```

Comment: @adaptron I updated the answer, the insert lines can only have column names with no prefixes.